# Compatibility between LuaLaTeX and the transparent package

Tags: luatex, transparent

If I run the example below with LuaLaTeX, the transparent package doesn't load with the error: `Package transparent Warning: Your pdfTeX version does not support color stacks.` (a pretty clear error message)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\transparent{0.5}{Ciao}
\end{document}
```

I have a bunch of images generated by Inkscape which contain the `\transparent` command, and at the moment I simply defined an empty `\transparent` command to avoid the error, but I'd like to know if there's a better workaround to maintain the transparency.

Comment: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/47

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `minimal` (see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)).

Two alternatives:

1. `standalone`

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{transparent}

   \begin{document}
   \transparent{0.5}{Ciao}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. `article` with the `luatex85` package:

   ```
   \RequirePackage{luatex85}
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{transparent}

   \begin{document}
   \transparent{0.5}{Ciao}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but the complete document is based on another class, `toptesi`, which I think is based on the class `report`. Adding the `luatex85` package in this case doesn't remove the error.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano For me, it does (add the luatex85 package, remove auxiliary files, recompile twice). I'm on TL2018 with LuaLaTeX 1.07.

Comment: Ah, yes, with the MWE it works but not with the full document. I gotta go now, but I'll investigate more later on.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Well, I just tried with toptesi and the procedure I described does work on an MWE with that class.

Comment: I'll try and get the package updated in the next few days so `luatex85` is not needed (`luatex85` should never be needed:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should is such a nice word :)

Comment: Ok, I've eventually figured out why this solution didn't work with the full document: that document also  included the package `pdfx` which apparently undefined the `\transparent` command. I removed the package `pdfx` (which is actually not needed) and now everything works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You're welcome. Yes, it's good that pdfx removes that, because in PDF/X transparency is unsupported.